# Qt C++11 lambda: Is this connect (signal-slot) correct?

Tags: qt, c++11, lambda, signals-slots

I am using Qt5 (C++11 enabled) on Windows7.
In my app I have something like this:

```
connect(ui->alarm, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, [this]{
  (ui->alarm->isChecked()) ? m_timer.start() : m_timer.stop();
});
```

where `alarm` is `QCheckBox` and `m_timer` is a `QTimer`.

I want to start/stop the timer on-the-fly, according to the status of the alarm check-box.

I tested, It seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's 100% ok... or **if there's a better lambda to do it**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
connect(ui->alarm, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, [this](int state){
  state ? m_timer.start() : m_timer.stop();
});
```

That way you don't need to refer to `ui->alarm`.

In `QCheckBox::stateChanged(int state)`, the `state` really is a

> enum Qt::CheckState
>
> **Qt::Unchecked** = 0 The item is unchecked.
>
> **Qt::PartiallyChecked** = 1 The item is partially checked. Items in hierarchical models may be partially checked if some, but not all, of their children are checked.
>
> **Qt::Checked** = 2 The item is checked.

Comment: Great! I will test it tomorrow, yet I guess it'll work just fine :)

Comment: The proper test would be: `if (state == Qt::Unchecked) m_timer.stop(); else if (state == Qt::Checked) m_timer.start();`. You should ignore the `PartiallyChecked` state!

Comment: One more thing: you can use signal toggled(bool checked) instead of stateChanged(int state)